# What is a paper and a set in Raphael.js

Tags: svg, raphael

1. What is  [***paper***](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper) and [***set***](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Set) in [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com)
2. Is it some external library reference..?
3. What is its use and how to use it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Paper is a Raphael reference to its main SVG element that it uses, a bit like a container (you can have several). It also has extra methods and variables, so its not 'just' an SVG element, but you can sort of think of it a bit like the main SVG element.

A Set is like an Array, thats used to store Raphael elements.

When its useful, is iterating over a large amount of Raph elements.

So you may do something like.

```
var mySet = paper.set();
mySet.push( myCircle, myRect, myOtherShapeCreatedEarlier);

mySet.forEach( function( el ) { doSomethingWithEachElement() } );
```

Also you may do something like...

```
var mySet = paper.selectAll('path');
mySet.attr({ opacity: "0" });
```

Which would make all the paths vanish.

So really a set is just a way of dealing with elements in an easy way.

Comment: Can I create a nested paper..? Has Raphael paper to do something with [Paper](http://paperjs.org/)..?

Comment: No PaperJS is something different, and paper is just really a term for an area that things are drawn on. I don't think you can add a Paper to another Paper (in SVG you can have nested SVGs though, if you needed more advanced features you may want to look at Snap.svg, however Raphael is better for old browser compatibility).